# Textbox toggle JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the below code wherein enabling and disabling of text box is not working:

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>TEST</title>
<!-- JQuery 1.12.3 JS -->
    <script src="../js/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><label class="control-label">Mode</label></td>
            <td>&nbsp;
                <label><input type="radio" name="payMode" value="cash" checked>Cash</label>
                <label><input type="radio" name="payMode" value="cheque">Cheque</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label>Cheque No</label></td>
            <td><input type="number" name="chequeNo" pattern="^[0-9]" min="0" step="1" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Cheque No" disabled></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label>Cheque Date</label></td>
            <td><input type="date" name="chequeDate" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Cheque Date" disabled></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<script>
 <script>
        $(':radio[name=payMode]').change(function () {
    var prop = this.value == 'cash';
    $('input[name=chequeNo], input[name=chequeDate]').prop({ disabled: prop, required: !prop });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Basically I am trying to enable 2 textboxes based on the radio click. Enable Cheque No and Cheque Date textbox if the user selects the Pay Mode as Cheque. If the user selects cash then disable the 2 textboxes. Please advice

Comment: [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/rpeyrs43/) working fine. what error you get?

Comment: @guradio you are right, code is working fine. I had duplicate script tags, hence the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two starting script tags, the inner script tag will cause a javascript error.

EDIT

Here is the link to the JSFiddle that proves it, I only removed the duplicate  tag. Sometimes the simple answers are the best :)

https://jsfiddle.net/0k98xnch/

```
<script>
        $(':radio[name=payMode]').change(function () {
    var prop = this.value == 'cash';
    $('input[name=chequeNo], input[name=chequeDate]').prop({ disabled: prop, required: !prop });
});
</script>
```

Comment: This in no way answers the question. This should be a comment

Comment: Well the inner script tag will cause a javascript error so yeah, it kind of does answer the question. How can I ever be sure, I just know that it is a problem, if that doesn't fix it he can comment back and I will help more

Comment: @Zach you are correct, it will not function with that extra `<script>` tag. Make it an answer with the demo as proof, sir.

Comment: @zer00ne, I am on mobile unfortunately but I will try to craft it one up here

Comment: @Zach Cut and paste the question code, make sure it's <script> tag for jQuery is an absolute path. Then comment out the extra <script> tag if you are able to.

Comment: @zer00ne I was able to make a jsfiddle to prove that it was indeed the issue and added it above. Looks like they got it figured out

Answer (score 2):

Example below shows when user change "payMode" radio button, Enable Cheque No and Cheque Date textbox if the user selects the Pay Mode as Cheque. If the user selects cash then disable and empty the 2 textboxes.

```js
$("input[name=payMode]").on("change", function(){
  if($(this).val() == "cheque"){
     $("input[name=chequeNo], input[name=chequeDate]").attr("disabled", false);
  }else{
     $("input[name=chequeNo], input[name=chequeDate]").val("").attr("disabled", true);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>TEST</title>
<!-- JQuery 1.12.3 JS -->
    <script src="../js/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><label class="control-label">Mode</label></td>
            <td>&nbsp;
                <label><input type="radio" name="payMode" value="cash" checked>Cash</label>
                <label><input type="radio" name="payMode" value="cheque">Cheque</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label>Cheque No</label></td>
            <td><input type="number" name="chequeNo" pattern="^[0-9]" min="0" step="1" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Cheque No" disabled></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label>Cheque Date</label></td>
            <td><input type="date" name="chequeDate" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Cheque Date" disabled></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```